# Remove canvas background color trying to show body background-images

Tags: html, canvas

I'm working in a new year them and i will find a canvas effect but my canvas background -color will be black i want to to remove canvas background color and  show my body images in canvas background .

Here my demo code   https://jsfiddle.net/pzg0zuog/

```
Do you have any idea how to remove this issues.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main function replace these two lines:

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

With this line:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
```

This will clear the canvas each frame rather than drawing a black rectangle over top of the canvas each frame.